# How do you create quickCheck properties with a Property output in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, sudoku, quickcheck

How do you create a property that checks that all solutions provided are valid solutions, I need it to output as a Property, but I'm unsure how to do that, I only understand how to do Bool outputs for quickCheck properties. See below for my attempt, and the general idea of how I want it to function:

```
solve :: Sudoku -> Maybe Sudoku
solve s = solve' (blanks s) s

solve' :: [Pos] -> Sudoku -> Maybe Sudoku
solve' blankl s
    | not (isOkay s)        = Nothing
    | isFilled s            = Just s
    | otherwise             = listToMaybe [fromJust sol | n <- [1..9], 
                                            let sol = solve' (tail blankl) (update s (head blankl) (Just n)),
                                            sol /= Nothing]

isSolutionOf :: Sudoku -> Sudoku -> Bool
isSolutionOf s1 s2 = 
    isOkay s1 
    && isFilled s1
    && and [ a == b || b == Nothing | 
             (a,b) <- zip (concat (rows s1)) (concat (rows s2)) ]

prop_SolveSound :: Sudoku -> Property
prop_SolveSound s 
    | solution == Nothing = True
    | otherwise           = isSolutionOf (fromJust solution) s where
                              solution = solve s
```

Any help is much appreciated, I guess what I'm asking is how can you convert the - quite clearly - `Bool` output from `prop_SolveSound` to a `Property` output?

Comment: "I need it to output as a Property" Why?

Comment: @MarkSeemann This is part of an assignment, they have deemed that it be the output.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense, but I suppose you could use one of the functions in [the QuickCheck library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) that return `Property`. Perhaps rewrite your property so that it compares expected and actual values with `===`, or perhaps the `total` function could be handy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very simplest, you can use [`property`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:property) method to convert e.g. `Bool` to `Property`. I suggest to look at the instances of [`Testable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Testable) class, and try to understand what each of them does, and how it can be used.

Or you can be more sophisticated and use some other functions returning `Property`, e.g. [`===`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:-61--61--61-). That might be tricky in your example.

One quite useful function, is [`counterexample`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:counterexample). It allows you to print additional output, when property doesn't hold. For example, it's used to implement `===`:

```
(===) :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> a -> Property
x === y =
  counterexample (show x ++ interpret res ++ show y) res
  where
    res = x == y
    interpret True  = " == "
    interpret False = " /= "
```

As this is an assignment, I'm not giving you any more hints.